# Does cherry-pick apply changes or try to merge the contents of the entire file?

Tags: git, git-cherry-pick

I'm reading [this article](http://think-like-a-git.net/sections/rebase-from-the-ground-up/cherry-picking-explained.html) about cherry-picking and there is the following picture there:

[image]

However, this picture seems misleading to me. From my simple test, it appears that, not just the difference, but the entire file content is merged. Here is the experiment:
I have this commit graph:

```
A--B
 \
  C
```

Commit `A` had this content in `file.txt`:

```
l1
l2
l3
```

Commit `B` had small change:

```
l1
l2-new
l3
```

Commit `C` had small change:

```
l1
l2
l3-new
```

So now I'm trying to replay commit `B` on the commit `C` using cherry-pick,

```
git cherry-pick B
```

and I get a conflict,

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
l2
l3-new
=======
l2-3
l3
>>>>>>> C
```

which should not be there if only changes were applied. Since I didn't touch `l2` line in my `C` commit, it should have applied smoothly. Am I right?

Comment: Your description is ambiguous. You say *"So now I'm trying to replay commit B on the commit C using cherry-pick:"* then you run `git cherry-pick C` which picks the commit `C` and attempts to apply it on the current `HEAD`. Where is the `HEAD` when you run this command? Then, the conflict you display doesn't match the content of the file on the two commits.

Comment: Sorry, I made changes to the question, and my HEAD is on the C commit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Git` stores files, but it generates and uses diffs in a lot of places.

A `diff` records the state of the affected lines before and after the commit; it also stores one line of text from before and after the modified area. `Git` uses this information to avoid data loss and inconsistencies.

Let's say we created branches named `A`, `B` and `C` on the commits having these names in your description.

```
$ git diff A B -- file.txt
diff --git a/file.txt b/file.txt
index f0f2307..0acba21 100644
--- a/file.txt
+++ b/file.txt
@@ -1,3 +1,3 @@
 l1
-l2
+l2-new
 l3
```

I asked `Git` to display the changes on file `file.txt` between commits `A` and `B`.

The format is a variation of the **uniffied diff format** and it is explained on the Wikipedia page about the [`diff utility`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff_utility#Unified_format).

In simple words, this `diff` says: change line 2 of the file from `l2` to `l2-new` but only if line 1 is `l1` and line 3 is `l3`. Even that only line 2 of the file was changed, `Git` includes also the lines 1 and line 3 of the file in the `diff`. They are the context of the change that happened on line 2.

**Remark:** In this case the file is small and lines 1-3 represent the entire file. `Git` doesn't use the entire file, it only guards any block of lines that changed with 1 line before the change and 1 line after the change. If, for example, the file has 20 lines and we change lines 12 and 13, the `diff` contains lines 11-14.

Back to what our `diff`, on commit `C` the file looks like:

```
l1
l2
l3-new
```

but in order to apply the `diff`, `Git` expects it to look like:

```
l1
l2
l3
```

Because its expectations are not met, `Git` cannot apply the `diff` safely and decides this is a conflict.

#### Why does `Git` need the context lines?

Let's say on commit `C` we deleted the second line. The file will look like:

```
l1
l3
```

Then we cherry-pick commit `B`, and apply the changes it introduced (change the line 2 from `l2` to `l2-new`) *without verifying the context*. The file will look now like:

```
l1
l2-new
```

Wait a moment! **Where is `l3`?**
I didn't delete the line `l3` on commit `C` and I didn't touch it on commit `B` either. **Applying a diff without checking the context, can lead to data loss.** `Git` always checks the context when it applies a diff and I suppose all the programs that work with diffs do the same.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the elaborate answer and a great explanation on how `git` decides whether there is a conflict. I'm going to read about `diff utility` as it seems to pretty crucial thing in `Git`. Does git uses the same logic when merging two commits, or there not the diff but the entire file's content is merged?

Comment: I cannot tell much about the `Git` internals. Using only the differences is the idea and I think most of the VCS programs implements it one way or another. The format of the diffs produced by git is (more or less) standard but it is just a way to represent the differences in a format that is human-readable and can be understood by other programs too. The merges are more complex because they need to combine the diffs that appears on two or more branches against their most recent common ancestor. Using a good visual compare & merge program helps you see the diffs and solve the conflicts easily.

Comment: According to [http://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff) the usual number of context lines is 3.

Answer (score 2):

You end up with a conflict because the changes are too close together (it terms of line number).  The context (generally the 3 lines surrounding the actual diff hunk) need to match, otherwise Git (and other version control systems) will flag the change as a conflict.  Since part of the context changed in your example, it was flagged as a conflict.

Comment: Yep, you're right. It seems that cherry-pick indeed takes the diff between commits. I've rearranged my test with more line breaks between text and it indeed applied only `l2-new` to the new commit.

Answer (score 0):

Git is storing files, not diffs, so mb since lines are close, git wasn't able to resolve it correctly.

Comment: Git only storing files and not diffs is not entirely true.  Take a look at the Git [pack format](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/technical/pack-format.txt).  It's not diffs as in unified diffs, but it is using deltas. :-)

Comment: @jszakmeister Aside from packs, that's true, though.

Comment: @Jubobs Isn't that basically what I said?

Comment: @jszakmeister Yes, we're on the same page. I'm merely pointing out that pack format is a detail; fundamentally, Git does store revisions, not diffs.

Comment: @Jubobs Gotcha.  I just wanted to make sure Andrew_Lvov knew there are deltas underneath the hood.  I've been helping folks fix Subversion repositories for years, and about half of them are surprised that there are deltas between revisions to reduce storage space.

Comment: @Andrew_Lvov It is true that Git stores only logical snapshots, but when applying a cherry-pick it uses diffs between to snapshots to determine the change.